# Slow Julia Startup Time

Tags: python, optimization, julia

I am exploring using Julia as a general purpose scientific computing language (as opposed to python), but it's startup time is pretty sluggish.

Is there any way of speeding this up?

```
$ time python -c 'print "Hello"'
Hello

real    0m0.030s
user    0m0.018s
sys 0m0.010s

$ time julia -e 'println("Hello")'
Hello

real    0m4.614s
user    0m4.644s
sys 0m0.116s
```

---

**ADDENDUM**: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711762/586893) is a quote from one of the Julia authors last year. Was there some difficulty with this strategy?

> Most of Julia is written in itself, then parsed, type-inferred and
>   jitted, so bootstrapping the entire system from scratch takes some
>   15-20 seconds. To make it faster, we have a staged system where we
>   parse, type-infer, and then cache a serialized version of the
>   type-inferred AST in the file sys.ji. This file is then loaded and
>   used to run the system when you run julia. No LLVM code or machine
>   code is cached in sys.ji, however, so all the LLVM jitting still needs
>   to be done every time julia starts up, which therefore takes about 2
>   seconds.
>
> This 2-second startup delay is quite annoying and we have a plan for
>   fixing it. The basic plan is to be able to compile whole Julia
>   programs to binaries: either executables that can be run or .so/.dylib
>   shared libraries that can be called from other programs as though they
>   were simply shared C libraries. The startup time for a binary will be
>   like any other C program, so the 2-second startup delay will vanish.

Comment: Now there is a branch in the Julialang repository you can check out. https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/4898. There are probably some issues still remaining, so try at your own risk. It will probably be included in the upcoming 0.3 release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [branch](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/4898) I mentioned in the comment has now been merged and julia is more optimized for startup (and doing nothing), than ever.

```
$> time julia -e 'println("Hello")'
Hello

real    0m0.622s
user    0m1.013s
sys     0m0.624s
```

This is now available in the nightly builds, and will be included in the next 0.3 release.

Comment: ```time julia -e 'println("Hello")'
Hello

real    1m35.137s
user    0m0.328s
sys     1m33.604s
```
And i am on julia 0.5.0 And this is a core i3 machine with 16GiB RAM and not a raspberry pi!

Comment: Seems like someting is wrong with your julia installation. What os are you using and how did you install julia

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I installed it from the ".tar.gz" file.

Comment: That is really strange, and I can't imagine what might cause startup to take one and a half minute. (Except maybe installing it on a network drive over a slow connection.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This was on my home server (installed and running there - not over the network storage) that remains on round the clock. Those numbers above were consistent across several runs. But, after a reboot I have - `real    0m0.730s
user    0m0.208s
sys     0m0.332s`

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately Julia currently uses a lot of time to start, so it is almost impossible to use it in a bash script for really small problems. You will probably get a result that favors julia more with a complicated example that uses loops to do things multiple times, but with 2-4 second head start it requires a large problem to have enough time catch up. If the startup time is the most important for your scientific computing, Julia isn't ready yet.

An equally unfair comparison is to look at computing fibonacci numbers using the stupid recursive formula. It gets much much worse if you go above 26. Also notice how compact the Julia version of the code is.

```
>>> ivarne~/dev/julia$ time julia -e 'fib(x) = x<2?1:fib(x-1)+fib(x-2);println(fib(36))'
24157817

real    0m2.763s
user    0m2.776s
sys     0m0.093s
>>> time python -c $'def fib(x):\n    if x<2: return 1\n    else: return fib(x-1)+ fib(x-2);\nprint fib(36)'
24157817

real    0m8.371s
user    0m8.336s
sys     0m0.025s
```

As you asked for a way to speed up the problem; here it is:

```
>>> time echo "Hello"
Hello

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the comparison is supposed to prove.  The Python version is buggy -- the two versions don't even compute the same number! -- and you could have written `fib = lambda x: 1 if x < 3 else fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)` if you cared about compactness, although usually Python programmers care about correctness and clarity more than characters.

Comment: I try to show that when you compare performance between Julia and Python, the result is highly dependent on the task you perform.

Comment: I'm not trying to find the most efficient echo ;-P  I was just wondering what the state-of-the-art is in reducing the overhead in julia

Comment: Hi, I'd just like to point out (I'm a Python user) that since if you're going to use Julia you might want to use it in an interactive environment, using Python with IPython you can still summon Cython. You can Cythonize that function on the fly with a minor type declaration (`def fib(int n): return 1 if n <= 2 else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`) and achieve (almost?) `C` performance.