# How can I improve the performance of my Julia program for excellent numbers?

Tags: performance, julia

I've been playing with some [Perl programs to calculate excellent numbers](http://www.masteringperl.org/2015/05/computing-excellent-numbers/). Although the runtimes for my solutions were acceptable, I thought a different language, especially one designed for numeric stuff, might be faster. A friend suggested [Julia](http://julialang.org), but the performance I'm seeing is so bad I must be doing something wrong. I've looked through the [Performance Tips](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/) and don't see what I should improve:

```
digits = int( ARGS[1] )

const k = div( digits, 2 )

for a = ( 10 ^ (k - 1) ) : ( 10 ^ (k) - 1 )
    front = a * (10 ^ k + a)

    root = floor( front ^ 0.5 )

    for b = ( root - 1 ): ( root + 1 )
        back = b * (b - 1);
        if back > front
            break
        end
        if log(10,b) > k
            continue
        end
        if front == back
            @printf "%d%d\n" a b
        end
    end
 end
```

I have an equivalent C program that's an order of magnitude faster instead of the factor of 2 noted on the [Julia page](http://julialang.org) (although most of the Stackoverflow questions about Julia's speed seem to point out flawed benchmarks from that page):

And the non-optimized pure Perl I wrote takes half as long:

```
use v5.20;

my $digits = $ARGV[0] // 2;
die "Number of digits must be even and non-zero! You said [$digits]\n"
    unless( $digits > 0 and $digits % 2 == 0 and int($digits) eq $digits );

my $k  = ( $digits / 2 );

foreach my $n ( 10**($k-1) .. 10**($k) - 1 ) {
    my $front = $n*(10**$k + $n);
    my $root = int( sqrt( $front ) );

    foreach my $try ( $root - 2 .. $root + 2 ) {
        my $back = $try * ($try - 1);
        last if length($try) > $k;
        last if $back > $front;
        # say "\tn: $n back: $back try: $try front: $front";
        if( $back == $front ) {
            say "$n$try";
            last;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using the pre-compiled Julia for Mac OS X since I couldn't get the source to compile (but I didn't try beyond it blowing up the first time). I figure that's part of it.

Also, I see about a 0.7 second start up time for any Julia program (see [Slow Julia Startup Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009824/slow-julia-startup-time)), which means the equivalent compiled C program can run about 200 times before Julia finishes once. As the runtime increases (bigger values of `digits`) and the startup time means less, my Julia program is still really slow.

I haven't gotten to the part for very large numbers (20+ digit excellent numbers) which I didn't realize Julia doesn't handle those any better than most other languages.

---

Here's my C code, which is a little different from when I started this. My rusty, inelegant C skills are essentially the same thing as my Perl.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    long 
        k, digits,
        start, end,
        a, b,
        front, back,
        root
        ;

    digits = atoi( argv[1] );

    k = digits / 2;

    start = (long) pow(10, k - 1);
    end   = (long) pow(10, k);

    for( a = start; a < end; a++ ) {
        front = (long) a * ( pow(10,k) + a );
        root  = (long) floor( sqrt( front ) );

        for( b = root - 1; b <= root + 1; b++ ) {
            back = (long) b * ( b - 1 );
            if( back > front )  { break; }
            if( log10(b) > k ) { continue; }
            if( front == back ) {
                printf( "%ld%ld\n", a, b );
                }
            }
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should include your actual benchmark timings, and some description of how you obtained them.

Comment: The standard library is pre-compiled in v0.3, but nothing else, hence the 0.7 second start up time. It looks like we're going to get compilation of packages in v0.4 - apparently it is already possible if you want to play around a bit (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-dev/qdnggTuIp9s)). So in other words, slowly but surely the obstacles to reducing start-up time are being knocked over one-by-one.

Comment: Also, wrapping your code in a function as suggested by @VincentZoonekynd gives a four factor speed-up on my machine. Not quite the performance you're after, but getting there.

Comment: Also also, out of curiosity, I had a quick look at the functional form using ProfileView. A disproportionate (to me) quantity of run-time on my machine is spent on `log(10, b)`. If `b` is always positive, there may be a macro for skipping the domain check in the `log` function, although I wouldn't have thought this would make a huge difference. Not an answer, but this might point you in the right direction for further reducing run-time

Comment: Huh... What do you know? Slow run-time of the log function in Julia is [issue #8869](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8869) on github. So I guess what you might be seeing here is simply some of the wrinkles that will hopefully be ironed out by v1.0.

Comment: @ColinTBowers I guess the answer is that Julia is slow. I didn't see any speed-up by wrapping the code in a function.

Comment: `I didn't see any speed-up by wrapping the code in a function` -that is odd. Moving from global to local scope provided a big speed-up for me. You would need to provide more detail on exactly how you are running your code to go further here (perhaps you are already in local scope)... `I guess the answer is that Julia is slow` -that is a very broad conclusion to draw from one very specific example on a language that is in beta. I'm sure you didn't mean it that way, but it comes across as inflammatory.

Answer (score 19):

I've benchmarked your code (`brian.jl`) against the following code, which attempts to make minimal changes to your code and follows Julian style:

```
function excellent(digits)
    k = div(digits, 2)
    l = 10 ^ (k - 1)
    u = (10 ^ k) - 1

    for a in l:u
        front = a * (10 ^ k + a)
        root = isqrt(front)
        for b = (root - 1):(root + 1)
            back = b * (b - 1)
            back > front && break
            log10(b) > k && continue
            front == back && println(a,b)
        end
    end
end
excellent(int(ARGS[1]))
```

Separating out `u` and `l` was a personal preference for readability. As a baseline, the Julia startup time on my machine is:

```
$ time julia -e ''
real    0m0.248s
user    0m0.306s
sys 0m0.091s
```

So if the computation you are running per execution of Julia from a cold start is on the order of 0.3 seconds, then Julia might not be a great choice for you at this stage. I passed in `16` to the scripts, and got:

```
$ time julia brian.jl 16
1045751633986928
1140820035650625
3333333466666668

real    0m15.973s
user    0m15.691s
sys     0m0.586s
```

and

```
$ time julia iain.jl 16
1045751633986928
1140820035650625
3333333466666668

real    0m9.691s
user    0m9.839s
sys     0m0.155s
```

A limitation of this code as written is that if `digits>=20` we will exceed the storage of a `Int64`. Julia, for performance reasons, doesn't auto-promote integer types to arbitrary precision integers. We can use our knowledge of the problem to address this by changing the last line to:

```
digits = int(ARGS[1])
excellent(digits >= 20 ? BigInt(digits) : digits)
```

We get the `BigInt` version of excellent for free, which is nice. Ignoring that for now, on profiling my version I found that ~74% of the time is spent calculating `log10`, following by ~19% on `isqrt`. I did this profiling by replacing the last line with

```
excellent(4)  # Warm up to avoid effects of JIT
@profile excellent(int(ARGS[1]))
Profile.print()
```

Now if we wanted to dabble in minor algorithmic changes, given what we know now from the profiler, we can replace the `log10` line (which is just checking the number of digits in effect) with `ndigits(b) > k && continue`, which gives us

```
$ time julia iain.jl 16
1045751633986928
1140820035650625
3333333466666668

real    0m3.634s
user    0m3.785s
sys     0m0.153s
```

This changes the balance to about ~56% from the `isqrt` and ~28% from `ndigits`. Digging further into that 56%, about half is spent executing [this line](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/d296fc6d8235e78a30f6d363b199e81dff6e74b5/base/intfuncs.jl#L292) which seems like a pretty sensible algorithm, so any improvement would probably change the spirit of the comparison as it'd really be a different approach altogether. Investigating the machine code with `@code_native` tends to suggest there is nothing else too strange going on, although I didn't dig deep into this.

If I allow myself to engage in some more minor algorithmic improvements, I can start from `root+1` and only doing the `ndigits` check once, i.e.

```
for a in l:u
    front = a * (10^k + a)
    root = isqrt(front)
    b = root + 1
    ndigits(b) > k && continue
    front == b*(b-1) && println(a,b)
    b = root
    front == b*(b-1) && println(a,b)
    b = root - 1
    front == b*(b-1) && println(a,b)
end
```

which gets me down to

```
real    0m2.901s
user    0m3.050s
sys     0m0.154s
```

(I'm not convinced the second two equality checks are needed, but I'm trying to minimize differences!). Finally I thought I'd eke out some extra speed by precomputing `10^k`, i.e. `k10 = 10^k`, which seems to be computed freshly each iteration. With that, I get to

```
real    0m2.518s
user    0m2.670s
sys     0m0.153s
```

Which is a fairly nice 20x improvement over the original code.

Comment: We can have the extra precision and wait days to see an answer, but that's not unique to Julia. :)

Comment: I used the in-built profiler - I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 12):

I was curious about how Perl was getting such good performance from this code, so I felt I ought to do a comparison. Since there are some seemingly needless differences in both control flow and operations between the Perl and Julia versions of the code in the question, I ported each version to the other language and compared all four. I also wrote a fifth Julia version using more idiomatic numerical functions but with the same control flow structure as the question's Perl version.

The first variant is essentially the Perl code from the question, but wrapped up in a function:

```
sub perl1 {
    my $k = $_[0];
    foreach my $n (10**($k-1) .. 10**($k)-1) {
        my $front = $n * (10**$k + $n);
        my $root = int(sqrt($front));

        foreach my $t ($root-2 .. $root+2) {
            my $back = $t * ($t - 1);
            last if length($t) > $k;
            last if $back > $front;
            if ($back == $front) {
                print STDERR "$n$t\n";
                last;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I translated this to Julia, keeping the same control flow and using the same operations – it takes the integer floor of the square root of `front` in the outer loop and takes the length of the "stringification" of `t` in the inner loop:

```
function julia1(k)
    for n = 10^(k-1):10^k-1
        front = n*(10^k + n)
        root = floor(Int,sqrt(front))

        for t = root-2:root+2
            back = t * (t - 1)
            length(string(t)) > k && break
            back > front && break
            if back == front
                println(STDERR,n,t)
                break
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Here's the question's Julia code with some minor formatting tweaks, wrapped up in a function:

```
function julia2(k)
    for a = 10^(k-1):10^k-1
        front = a * (10^k + a)
        root = floor(front^0.5)

        for b = root-1:root+1
            back = b * (b - 1);
            back > front && break
            log(10,b) > k && continue
            if front == back
                @printf STDERR "%d%d\n" a b
                # missing break?
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I translated this back to Perl, keeping the same control flow structure and using the same operations as the Perl code – taking floor of `root` raised to the 0.5 power in the outer loop, and taking the logarithm base 10 in the inner loop:

```
sub perl2 {
    my $k = $_[0];
    foreach my $a (10**($k-1) .. 10**($k)-1) {
        my $front = $a * (10**$k + $a);
        my $root = int($front**0.5);

        foreach my $b ($root-1 .. $root+1) {
            my $back = $b * ($b - 1);
            last if $back > $front;
            next if log($b)/log(10) > $k;
            if ($front == $back) {
                print STDERR "$a$b\n"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I wrote a Julia version that has the same control flow structure as the question's Perl version but uses more idiomatic numerical operations – the `isqrt` and `ndigits` functions:

```
function julia3(k)
    for n = 10^(k-1):10^k-1
        front = n*(10^k + n)
        root = isqrt(front)

        for t = root-2:root+2
            back = t * (t - 1)
            ndigits(t) > k && break
            back > front && break
            if back == front
                println(STDERR,n,t)
                break
            end
        end
    end
end
```

As far as I know (I used to do a lot of Perl programming, but it's been a while), there aren't Perl versions of either of these operations, so there's no corresponding `perl3` variant.

I ran all five variations with Perl 5.18.2 and Julia 0.3.9, respectively, ten times each for 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 and 14 digits. Here are the timing results:

[image: median execution time in seconds vs. digits]

The x axis is the number of digits requested. The y axis is median time in seconds required to compute each function. The y axis is plotted on a log scale (there's some rendering bug in the Cairo backend of [Gadfly](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl), so the superscripts don't appear very raised). We can see that except for the very smallest number of digits (2), all three Julia variants are faster than both Perl variants – and `julia3` is substantially faster than everything else. How much faster? Here's a comparison of the other four variants relative to `julia3` (not log scale):

[image: time relative to julia3 vs. digits]

The x axis is the number of digits requested again, while the y axis is how many times slower each variant was than `julia3`. As you can see here, I was unable to reproduce the Perl performance claimed in the question – the Perl code was not 2x faster than Julia – it was 7 to 40 times slower than `julia3` and at least 2x slower than the slowest Julia variant for any non-trivial number of digits. I didn't test with Perl 5.20 – perhaps someone could follow up by running these benchmarks with a newer Perl and see if that explains the different results? Code to run the benchmarks can be found here: [excellent.pl](https://gist.github.com/StefanKarpinski/f11505c3153fc2964659), [excellent.jl](https://gist.github.com/StefanKarpinski/43a31921d4b7c7d17898). I ran the them like this:

```
cat /dev/null >excellent.csv
for d in 2 4 6 8 10 12 14; do
    perl excellent.pl $d >>excellent.csv
    julia excellent.jl $d >>excellent.csv
done
```

I analyzed the resulting [`excellent.csv`](https://gist.github.com/StefanKarpinski/07558c0b8e2f05ab32d3) file using [this Julia script](https://gist.github.com/StefanKarpinski/9e21fca61f25798db32e).

Finally, as has been mentioned in the comments, using `BigInt` or `Int128` is an option for exploring larger excellent numbers in Julia. However, this requires a little care for writing the algorithm generically. Here's a fourth variation that works generically:

```
function julia4(k)
    ten = oftype(k,10)
    for n = ten^(k-1):ten^k-1
        front = n*(ten^k + n)
        root = isqrt(front)

        for t = root-2:root+2
            back = t * (t - 1)
            ndigits(t) > k && break
            back > front && break
            if back == front
                println(STDERR,n,t)
                break
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This is the same as `julia3` but works for generic integer types by converting 10 to the type of its argument. Since the algorithm scales exponentially, however, it still takes a very long time to compute for any number of digits much larger than 14:

```
julia> @time julia4(int128(10)) # digits = 20
21733880705143685100
22847252005297850625
23037747345324014028
23921499005444619376
24981063345587629068
26396551105776186476
31698125906461101900
33333333346666666668
34683468346834683468
35020266906876369525
36160444847016852753
36412684107047802476
46399675808241903600
46401324208242096401
48179452108449381525
elapsed time: 2260.27479767 seconds (5144 bytes allocated)
```

It works, but 37 minutes is kind of a long time to wait. Using a faster programming language only gets you a constant factor speedup – 40x in this case – but that only buys a couple of extra digits. To really explore larger excellent numbers, you'll need to look into better algorithms.

Comment: I just realized the inner loop varies between `root-1:root+1` and `root-2:root+2` between versions in the OP and here - I guess it didn't matter for me because I wasn't trying to compare against the Perl version.

Comment: Yeah, the Perl and Julia versions in the question are pretty different. That's why I ported them both ways and did the multiway comparison.

Comment: I didn't make any claims about Perl being faster. I said my C was much faster than the Julia webpage would have me believe.

Comment: @briandfoy – you wrote "the non-optimized pure Perl I wrote takes half as long". What was the comparison to if not the Julia version?

Comment: The comparison to C would also be interesting. I would expect that calling the same functions in Julia as called in C would produce the same performance. The `julia3` variant, which is 40x faster than Perl is in the right ballpark. If you post the C code as well, we could add that to these benchmarks.

Comment: This is a great comparison.  Nicely done. That said, I believe all of @briandfoy's performance issues stemmed from timing the Julia code externally as a standalone script, which includes startup and compilation time.  Julia is in this strange middle-ground; you wouldn't include compilation time in a C benchmark, but since we don't support caching or outputting compiled binaries yet it's not entirely unreasonable to include it for Julia.

Comment: Well, to be fair I think the performance of log() has a lot to do with it, and I was using some functions that had to do implicit conversions. I posted my C code, which is a straight port from my Perl.

Answer (score 4):

I get a big speedup when I use `ifloor` (which isn't listed in [Mathematical Operations and Elementary Functions](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/mathematical-operations/)) instead of `floor`. Getting rid of either `floor` in favor of `isqrt` shows the same speedup. I don't see where that is documented either.

Now I see performance that I would expect, although on my Mac, it looks like Julia couldn't start k = 10. `BigInt` can help that but then the performance is rotten. Part of the reason I looked at Julia was my hope that it could easily handle bigger numbers, so I'll have to keep looking at that.

The rest of the expected speed might be hidden in the implementation of the logarithm algorithms, as Colin noted in the comments.

I had fun checking out this language, and maybe I'll try again when it's mature.

Comment: Final thought: You could likely get further optimisations from the [julia-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/julia-users) group. The core devs regularly monitor the threads, and questions about performance are taken very seriously...

Comment: [`ifloor`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/math/#Base.ifloor) is in the 0.3 docs (current release), but has been deprecated in the development version (which are the docs you're seeing) in favour of `floor(Int,x)`

Comment: [Here is the 0.3 manual](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.3/manual/mathematical-operations/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to to put your code in a function.

```
function excellent(k)
  for a = ( 10 ^ (k - 1) ) : ( 10 ^ (k) - 1 )
    front = a * (10 ^ k + a)
    root = ifloor( sqrt(front) ) # floor() returns a double

    for b = ( root - 1 ): ( root + 1 )
      back = b * (b - 1);
      if back > front
        break
      end
      if log(10,b) > k
        continue
      end
      if front == back
        @printf "%d%d\n" a b
      end
   end
  end
end

@time excellent(7)
## 33333346666668
## 48484848484848
## elapsed time: 1.451842881 seconds (14680 bytes allocated)
```

For arbitrary-precision numbers, you can use BigInt (e.g., `ten = BigInt("10")`, but the performance drops...

Comment: I tried putting the code in a function. There was no difference in time. 1.45 seconds is very, very slow.

Comment: This code doesn't work for me with k > 8. I get a DomainError.

Comment: This also doesn't take the number of digits from the command line, which is a very useful part of the program.

Comment: The `ifloor` is much faster.

Comment: @briandfoy `isqrt` might help with that step

Comment: I removed the command-line argument part of your program because I could see no obvious improvement to make to it.
The argument of the function is `k`, which is half the number of digits:
7 corresponds to 14 digits, for which your Perl program took 15 seconds on my machine.
The `DomainError` is caused by integer overflow: `front` becomes negative, and the square root fails.
For `k>9`, you could use longer integers: `Int128` is only 3 times slower and will allow twice as many digits.