# Why does the Julia compiler not create an executable file?

Tags: compilation, julia

I'm used to having compilers create a .exe after compiling some code. That doesn't seem to happen in Julia though.

Unless I'm doing something wrong, it seems only the interactive JIT compiler can be used, making it seem almost like an interpreted language.

Can one make .exes using `$ julia filename` or not? How is Julia a compiled language if it doesn't actually create a binary? I'm pretty new to programming in general, but I'm pretty sure the concept of compiling is translating a file into machine code, I don't understand what exactly would make the JIT compiler obligatory in Julia's case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268028/julia-compiles-the-script-everytime

Comment: Just be aware, things are changing quickly in the world of Julia. Static compilation appears to be on the way, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-dev/qdnggTuIp9s) or [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/8656). I'm not sure if it'll be in the v0.4 release though...